# How to prove a complete binary tree of depth N has $2^{N+1} - 1$ nodes?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Here is the description of a proof problem:

A complete binary tree of depth **N** is a binary tree in which every node on levels $0,1,2,...,N-1$ is a parent and has two children, and each node on level **N** is a leaf.

It's asking for *proving binary tree of depth N has $2^{N+1} - 1$ nodes*.

I am not really sure how to approach this proof. I tried to plug in some values in $D(N) = 2^{N+1} - 1$ just to play with the formula, I get $D(1) = 2^{1+1} - 1 = 3$,  $D(2) = 2^{2+1} - 1 = 7$, $D(3) = 2^{3+1} - 1 = 15$, and so on. I still did not see how these numbers relate to the descriptions given and how I would relate these values to given facts to build a proof.

Comment: Your claim is true if only the tree is a perfect binary tree. A complete tree may have fewer than $2^{N+1}-1$ nodes. A [**perfect** binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) is a binary tree in which all interior nodes have two children and all leaves have the same depth or same level.

Comment: [Related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/how-can-i-prove-that-a-complete-binary-tree-has-lceil-n-2-rceil-leaves?rq=1). Also [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/what-is-the-depth-of-a-complete-binary-tree-with-n-nodes?rq=1). Duplicate?

Comment: @fade2black There are multiple competing definitions of "complete binary tree". Unfortunately, the definition in the question doesn't work: a path is a "complete binary tree" by this definition, since it doesn't require interior nodes to have two children.

Comment: @fade2black Correct: the given definition doesn't imply any specific number of nodes. As I said, a path fits the definition and has only $N$ nodes.

Comment: Your definition is missing the following part: each node on levels $1,2,\ldots,N-1$ is a parent **and has two children**, and each node on level $N$ is a leaf.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I overlooked the two children part there. But doesn't having two children makes the complete binary tree a full binary tree? This has gotten me quite confused since I use this [source](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html).

Comment: Well, it's clearly the right definition here. As for the concepts *complete* and *full*, they are not as standard as some people here seem to think, and might mean slightly different things to different people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Draw some binary trees of depth $0, 1, 2$ and $3$. Depth $0$ is only the the root.

**Hint 2:** Use [Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) on the depth of the tree to derive a proof.

The base case is depth $n=0$. With depth $0$ we only have the root, that is, $2^{0 + 1} - 1 = 1$ nodes, so the formula is valid for $n=0$.

The next case is depth $n=0+1=1$, since the tree is full the root must have $2$ leafs. So we have $1 + 2 = 3$ nodes in total. The formula still holds since $2^{1+1} - 1 = 3$.

Can you generalize this procedure? Does this hold for all $n \geq 0$?

Comment: It is not clear how this proves that the [complete binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) of depth $N$ has $2^{N+1} - 1$ nodes. It may also have $2^{N+1} - 3$ or  $2^{N+1} - 5$ nodes.

Comment: @fade2black If "complete binary tree of depth $N$" isn't uniquely determined, then you need to be saying "a complete binary tree", not "the".